# How to check list has all array items?

Tags: c#, linq

I have array of items and List of string. I need to check if list has all items of array. If yes return true or false. Will possible check with LINQ?

I tried `bool flag = stringlst.Contains(new string[] { "DC", "DL", "ARP" });` it didn't work.

Note: List will have more items than the array. Array is subset of list.

Comment: Are the items guaranteed to be any particular order? (It could make the check more efficient.)

Comment: Order will be different and List is superset and has more items than the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure that the list contains all the items that are in a certain array (or any other `IEnumerable`), you may use the [`Except()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except).

**Example:**

```
var stringlst = new List<string> { "Foo", "DC", "DL", "ARP", "Bar" };
var arr = new string[] { "DC", "DL", "ARP" };
bool listContainsAll = !arr.Except(stringlst).Any();    // True
```

---

Here's a generic extension method to make it easier in case it's going to be used a lot:

```
public static bool ContainsAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    return !values.Except(source).Any();
}
```

**Usage:**

```
bool listContainsAll = stringlst.ContainsAll(new string[] { "DC", "DL", "ARP" });
```

Answer (score 1):

[`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) is your friend here. Providing you can store the strings you are expecting in the list in a `HashSet<T>`, the [`IsSubsetOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.issubsetof) method computes the required information:

```
var expected = new HashSet<string> { "DC", "DL", "ARP" };
bool containsAllExpected = expected.IsSubsetOf(stringlst);
```

It's efficient (O(n+m)) and no intermediate collection is created. In addition, if you can modify the `expected` set, using the [`ExceptWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.exceptwith) method is even faster (O(n)):

```
expected.ExceptWith(stringlst);
bool containsAllExpected = expected.Count == 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In *general case* when we have to count *duplicates* (which are *ignored* by `Except`) we can use `GroupBy` and check for groups:

```
  List<string> stringList = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C", "B", "A", "A" };

  // "A" should appear at least 3 times, "B" at least once
  string[] arr = new string[] { "A", "B", "A", "A" };

  var actual = stringList
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());

  bool flag = arr
    .GroupBy(item => item)
    .All(group => actual.TryGetValue(group.Key, out var count) && count >= group.Count());
```